# I've got Could not find or load main class when I try to run my java code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

so, I was running my java code in intellij idea, then I got the 
[following error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiN4J.png)

then I tried changing java SDK from v.12 to v.11, the the other projects that worked correctly, outputs the same results.

This is the code that i'm trying to run. an example from Deitel How To Program Java.

```
package ConcurrentProgramming.ParallelAndNonParallel;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        int[] array1 = random.ints(15_000_000).toArray();
        int[] array2 = new int[array1.length];

        System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array2, 0, array1.length);

        System.out.println("Starting sort");
        Instant sortStart = Instant.now();
        Arrays.sort(array1);
        Instant sortEnd = Instant.now();

        long sortTime = Duration.between(sortStart, sortEnd).toMillis();
        System.out.printf("Total time in milliseconds: %d%n%n", sortTime);

        System.out.println("Starting parallelSort");
        Instant parallelSortStart = Instant.now();
        Arrays.parallelSort(array2);
        Instant parallelSortEnd = Instant.now();

        long parallelSortTime =
                Duration.between(parallelSortStart, parallelSortEnd).toMillis();
        System.out.printf("Total time in milliseconds: %d%n%n",
                parallelSortTime);

        String percentage = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(
                (double) sortTime / parallelSortTime);
        System.out.printf("\nsort took %s more time than parallelSort%n",
                percentage);

    }
}
```

and here is my [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNZIX.png)

Comment: Could you post your SortComparison class please ?

Comment: What is the directory structure in your project? I mean what directory contains `SortComparison.java`?

Comment: of course. I've just updated my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the code didn't compile or it's not on the classpath. I'm not an IntelliJ user, so I can't tell you which based on what you have provided.

Check that the class is being compiled - You should see it here (assuming the out directory is where IntelliJ is putting the classes):

`LearningJava\out\ConcurrentProgramming\ParallelAndNonParallel\SortComparison.class`

If it's not there, then it's a problem with IntelliJ not compiling the class or building the project.

If it's there, try running it from the command line directly:

`java -cp <path-to-out> ConcurrentProgramming.ParallelAndNonParallel.SortComparison`

If that works, it's an issue with IntelliJ setting the proper classpath.

Comment: I've tried running my code using cmd. it works. the problem is intellij. it was working fine suddenly all hell broke loose.

Comment: It's probably just a setting that got flipped. IDEs can be tempermental sometimes. I have not devoted the time to IntelliJ enough to help. Sorry